# Non-KDE alternative to KNotes?

Tags: software-rec, productivity, notes

Do you know a [KNotes](http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/knotes/)-like program that does not require the whole KDE stuff?

To anybody not knowing KNotes, this is what it does and how it looks like:
[image: KNotes screenshot from kde.org]

Answer (score 2):

[xpad](http://packages.debian.org/sid/xpad) uses gtk (so does sticky-notes), [xpostit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/xpostit/3.3.1-9) requires neither GTK nor KDE. There are probably more available.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Gnote](http://live.gnome.org/Gnote)?  Its a C++ port of [Tomboy](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/), and usually has better performance.  Tomboy itself is written in C#, so it requires the Mono runtime.  Gnote has been able to completely replace Tomboy for me, and I was more than happy to remove Mono. You did not say if GNOME applications were acceptable, but regardless it has almost zero GNOME dependencies.